# Windows Reserve file necessary while using ubuntu only?

Tags: partitioning

I was using windiows 10 sometime ago, but now I am using ubuntu.
If I deleted the system reservd partition (500mb), is that will creat any problem for me??
or any effect on my hard disk?? I also don't want to lose my other drives' files...

[image]

Comment: You are using Ubuntu now. Ok. Installed in UEFI mode or BIOS mode? can you attach a screen shot after opening "GParted" from Ubuntu.

Comment: It is highly possible to be your UEFI partition. If you are using UEFI mode do not delete this partition.

Comment: ss is given,  now I'm in live ubuntu 16.04, because for the reserved partition I'm faceing errors and my ubuntu 17.10 crushed....  I want to install again, but what should I do?? delete the system reserved partition?

Comment: If this is a new installation you can delete this partition. But if you are using UEFI  you should create another small partition reserved to it.

Comment: @ShifaT as per the attached pic, you dont have EFI Partition, meaning you installed in BIOS Mode. sda4 contains your data. if you want to make fresh installation.. you can delete that System Reserved partition and go with UEFI mode, first create 100mb EFI Partition. Then Create your ext4 mounted to / and then swap file.

Comment: @PRATAP Consider turning your comment to an answer.

Comment: should i select efi partition for bootloader installation ??

Comment: for bootloade installation you should select whole drive. sda